# TextInputEditText drawableEnd change color on Error

Tags: android, android-layout, material-components-android, android-textinputlayout

How to change the color of a drawableEnd svg-icon when there is an error ?

```
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/tiMail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/tieMail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/new_contact_activity_mail_hint"
        android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress">

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText>
```

[image: img]

[image: img]

I would like the email icon to turn red on error

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    app:endIconMode="custom"
    app:endIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_email"
```

instead of

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
 android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_email"
```

Comment: Well now it just got grey all the time  https://ibb.co/S00Yvtq https://ibb.co/MgptC59

Comment: @LeursDimitri which version of material components are you using?

Comment: implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'

Comment: Any help ? please

Answer (score 0):

You can use `app:endIconDrawable` instead of `android:drawableEnd`. But do not forget to set `app:endIconTint` if you want to change the drawable's colour.

For example:

```
 app:endIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_add_sticker"
 app:endIconMode="custom"
 app:endIconTint="#808080"
```